# OWIN Authentication Cookie information and forcing login even when not expired

Tags: authentication, cookies, model-view-controller, owin

I want to provide two pieces of functionality to an MVC 5 (OWIN) website for the Authentication Cookies:-

- Show cookie expiration for each user
- Force a login, even if a cookie is not expired

Once a user is logged in, the cookie and its contained claims are on their browser.

I've managed to get the cookie information, although it does this on every visit to the server.

As far as forcing a login is concerned, I either have to update the cookie (not possible if the user isn't interacting with the site) or look for a user by name on each login.

My answer is below - if anyone has a better one, please let me know

Answer (score 0):

In the OWIN start-up class I added a custom identity validation method. An administrator can set a field in the Identity Database to force a login next time around. A downside is a hit on the database each time a user visits a web page.

If a user must login this time, Forced Login flag is cleared, the user logged off and redirected to the Home page which then goes to the login page (and redirect back to the Home page after login).

This code also retrieves the cookie information for display in the list of users that an administrator can view.

```
private static Task MyCustomValidateIdentity(CookieValidateIdentityContext context)
        {
            var db = ApplicationDbContext.Create();
            var userName = context.Identity.GetUserName();
            var user = (from u in db.Users where u.UserName == userName select u).FirstOrDefault();

            if (user != null)
            {
                if (user.ForceLoginNextTime)
                {
                    user.ForceLoginNextTime = false;
                    db.SaveChanges();

                    context.OwinContext.Authentication.SignOut(context.Options.AuthenticationType);
                    context.Response.Redirect("/Home");
                }
            }

            var i = (from u in __userInfo where u.userName == userName select u).FirstOrDefault();

            if (i == null)
            {
                i = new UserInfo();
                __userInfo.Add(i);
            }

            i.userName = userName;
            i.CookieIssuedUtc = context.Properties.IssuedUtc;
            i.CookieExpiresUtc = context.Properties.ExpiresUtc;
            i.CookieIsPersistent = context.Properties.IsPersistent;

            return Task.FromResult(0);
        }
```